# Spring repository: HQL using constructor doens't parse NULL values

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I've a Spring Repository with this HQL query:

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Query(value = "SELECT new mypackage.PupillaryDistanceDTO(e.pupillaryDistanceFarTot,e.pupillaryDistanceFarDx,e.pupillaryDistanceFarSx,null ,null,null,null,null,null,e.pupillaryDistanceNearTot,e.pupillaryDistanceNearDx,e.pupillaryDistanceNearSx) FROM EyeExamination e WHERE e.contact.id=:contactId ORDER BY e.id DESC")
    Page<PupillaryDistanceDTO> findLastPupillaryDistance(@Param("contactId") long contactId, Pageable pageable);
```

`PupillaryDistanceDTO` is a POJO annotated with `@AllArgsConstructor`(Lombok); unfortunately those `null` values I want to pass to the constructor are creating some troubles:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.NameGenerator.generateColumnNames(NameGenerator.java:27) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.generateColumnNames(SessionFactoryHelper.java:434) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeColumnNames(SelectClause.java:268) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.finishInitialization(SelectClause.java:258) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeExplicitSelectClause(SelectClause.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.useSelectClause(HqlSqlWalker.java:1026) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processQuery(HqlSqlWalker.java:794) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:689) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:325) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:273) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:716) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor150.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy267.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:56) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:146) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:216) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:100) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1056) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[?:?]
```

Removing those `null` and replacing with some table's columns, it works. Is there a way to tell Hibernate to interpret those `null` in the right way?

Comment: No that's no possible. Why don't you create a matching constructor?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I've 12 fields, all of them are BigDecimal and it would not be so clear, but if it's the only solution, I'll go with it. Thanks!

Comment: Consider query by example.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use `nullif(1,1)` to emulate the null, but it would be better to just create an appropriate constructor that doesn't require passing nulls.

Answer (score 1):

I think that passsing null values to constructor is not right as @Christian Beikov said. Instead of this, you can create appropriate constructor.